# mysql - how to get index of matching one column to another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a situation where I have a table 1 like this:

```
Id   Name   
---------
1    C  
2    A  
3    B 
4    B  
5    B    
6    A
```

And I have a table 2 like this (id, name here are the same as id, name in table 1):

```
Id   Name   
---------
1    A
1    B
1    C  
2    A 
2    C  
3    B    
4    A 
4    B
5    B
6    A
```

That is, table 2 has the same ids as table 1 but mapped to multiple names. I have sorted each set of names (A, B, C) for each id in table 2 but as shown each id may not map to all 3. I would like to make a query which returns for each id, the index of the value in table A in the group of values corresponding to the id in table B. That is, I want the following table:

```
Id   Name   
---------
1    3  
2    1  
3    1 
4    2  
5    1    
6    1
```

As you can see for Id = 2 for example, table 1 has name 'A'. In table 2 has names 'A' and 'C' for Id = 2. Since 'A' is the first member of the list ['A', 'C'] 1 is returned in the final query.

What is the best way to write this query?

Comment: You aren't posting a problem anyone can help you with -- we cannot see the actual tables, their setup, or any query you are actually trying. Please rephrase your question to include steps you have already taken to come to a solution

Comment: what mySql version are you using?

Comment: It looks a bit like a homework question, or getting work done for free, but the question itself contains enough information to write an answer...

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to posting, I did try several things which in retrospect I should have provided with extra information. Answer gave me what I needed already, so I'll be more informative in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39508/7)**

```
select 
  t1.id as Id, 
  find_in_set(t1.name, group_concat(t2.Name order by t2.id)) as Name
from source t1
join target t2 on t1.id=t2.id
group by t1.id
```

- Join the two tables based on ID.
- Group by t1.id because we want want one row per id in the first table.
- We concatenate the names from the second table into a string
- Get the index in that string using `find_in_set`

Thanks to Juan Carlos Oropeza for setting up an SQL fiddle!

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: Nice idea to create a fiddle.. I just wrote the query from the top of my head without running it on a database.. turns out I should order within the group_concat; else the results are not stable.

Comment: Yes, I was going to ask about that, but then see the low quality question and (*shame on me*) look the other way

Comment: The thing is we assume the index is based on the order by Name, but experience has teach me assuming very often get you wrong result. So we have to ask OP if that is the result he want or he have any intrinsic order. If that is the case we have to teach him tables are **UNORDER** dataset